# Cant launch mutter to get it to return errors after installing it

Tags: mutter

I just downloaded and installed mutter rounded on Ubuntu 22.04 but after installation, I can't launch mutter to get it to return errors.

```
(gjs:7213): Gjs-CRITICAL **: 10:01:03.396: JS ERROR: Error: GSettings key clip-edge-padding not found in schema org.gnome.mutter
_checkKey@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/core/overrides/Gio.js:580:23
createCheckedMethod/<@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/core/overrides/Gio.js:532:30
@mutter_settings.js:1:22437
@mutter_settings.js:1:27804
@mutter_settings.js:1:27808


(gjs:7213): Gjs-CRITICAL **: 10:01:03.396: Script mutter_settings.js threw an exception
```

Answer (score 0):

When the system updates mutter-common and some related packages, it replaces the downloaded versions that you installed and causes the `GSettings key clip-edge-padding not found in schema org.gnome.mutter` issue.

**You should be able to [resinstall mutter-rounded](https://github.com/yilozt/mutter-rounded#ubuntu-2110--ubuntu-2204) to fix the issue.**

However, the problem will appear again if a system update replaces these packages. When this happens, you will simply have to reinstall mutter-rounded again.

---

There is a workaround below but keep in mind that this workaround **is not ideal because placing the packages on hold will prevent security updates** for the packages on hold.

Because of this, the following workaround is **not recommended**. You can apply the workaround below but keep in mind that the workaround will possibly expose you to lack of security updates for the packages on hold.

According to [this thread](https://github.com/yilozt/mutter-rounded-setting/issues/1#issuecomment-1157539567), you can run the following commands as a workaround to hold the packages and prevent updates.

```
sudo apt-mark hold libmutter-10-0
sudo apt-mark hold libmutter-10-dev
sudo apt-mark hold mutter-common
```

After you hold the packages, reinstall mutter-rounded and then it should work again.

Lastly, you can run the following commands if you need to revert the changes made by the workaround (allow future updates of these packages).

```
sudo apt-mark unhold gir1.2-mutter-10
sudo apt-mark unhold libmutter-10-0
sudo apt-mark unhold libmutter-10-dev
sudo apt-mark unhold mutter-common
```